# Inserting a news-feed widget to a page

Tags: haskell, yesod

I have a page I'd like to embed a news-feed widget into (so that the feed from some remote site will be displayed in my site).

While there are quite a few free news-feed widgets available out there (a partial list is here: http://allwebco-templates.com/support/S_script_newsfeed.htm), They all require insertion of complex code into the html page, while all the parameters are hard-coded into the generated code, which looks something like this:

```
insertedWidgetText = "<script id=\"scrnewsblock10795953\" type=\"text/javascript\">...script specific parameters go here...</script>"

let feedWidget = toWidgetBody [hamlet|#{preEscapedText insertedWidgetText}|]
```

This doesn't integrate well with Yesod's approach as it requires specifying to Hamlet that the content is preEscapedText, which in turn disables the ability to use Hamlet's processing to alter parameters of the widget dynamically (So in case I want the widget to use a different source, for example, I need to statically change the quoted text and cannot use Hamlet's variable substitution).

Of course I could do some text manipulation myself, tailor built for the widget I'm using, but that doesn't seem like the "right" solution (especially if I want to have the embedded text in some external file and not in the middle of my code as in the example above).

Can the above mentioned issue have a better solution than the one I thought about?

Is there an implementation of a news-feed widget in Haskell/Yesod that I can use as a plugin?

Note: I'm a very poor javascript programmer, but solutions in that direction are also welcomed.

Thanks,